# trying to run a program on my device ... I still get this problem, I tried to solve it but I never managed to

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, conda

the program from ( https://github.com/sniklaus/sepconv-slomo ) ...
I tried to run the program using anaconda prompt.. and used "python run.py --model lf --first ./images/first.png --second ./images/second.png --out ./out.png" instruction as said ... but all I had was this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBKoF.png)

I did everything written in the setup section but it never worked.
Although I installed torch and cupy, but the problem is still the same.
I think it would work if I ran the program on my cpu -I think gpu caused the problem- .. but I did not know how to do so.

Comment: Can you share what exactly you did to set up the environment and program?

Comment: first downloaded the pretrained model then downloaded cupy using conda install cupy.
They did not mentioned more than these steps!!

Comment: Did you install cupy in a new environment? What packages were installed?

Comment: No, I did not install cupy in a new environment.

Comment: It's probably worth a try, then.